# Add password policy to Alfresco

Tags: jakarta-ee, alfresco, password-policy

Hi i'm new in Alfresco and i want to know if there is a way to add policy password to Users :

- Password must containt > 8 Char
- Password must containt Lower and Upper Cast
- Password must containt Special Char

Answer (score 2):

Be warned that this might not be the easiest thing to do for somebody who just started working with alfresco.

First, Alfresco can only enforce a policy if passwords are stored in Alfresco (and you do not authenticate against an external system such as Active Directory).

**Edit: Behaviour won't work because password is  encoded**:

To make sure it is impossible to set a password not compliant with your policy, you should implement a `OnUpdatePropertiesPolicy` ( http://dev.alfresco.com/resource/docs/java/repository/org/alfresco/repo/node/NodeServicePolicies.OnUpdatePropertiesPolicy.html) on type `usr:user` verifying the property `usr:password` and hook in into the system (http://docs.alfresco.com/4.2/concepts/content-behavior.html).

**Edit: Password policy needs cleartext password**

You need to override `passwordGenerator` and `sha256PasswordEncoder` defined in `WEB-INF/classes/alfresco/authentication-services-context.xml` and user-interface components (in Share) so you don't get people to see ugly exceptions thrown by the encoders.

Comment: Thanks Andreas, the link you gave on alfresco dev is unfortunately broken.
I've found the following resource interesting to understand how Alfresco handles behaviors :
http://docs.alfresco.com/5.1/references/dev-extension-points-behaviors.html